# SELECT DISTINCT FROM 3 columns with all the records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to query and get for all the records with the same datetime ,filter by Type , Provider and Operator.
If I run select distinct EventStamp I get all the records that I need, but I miss the type , provider and operator.
Like the screenshots if I have the Type OPR  I need this record
If all the types are DDE I need Provider RDSSERVER\Intouch.

[image]

```
 SELECT [EventStamp] ,[TagName] ,[Description],[Area] ,[Type],[Value], Antes FROM
(
SELECT distinct [EventStamp]
      ,[TagName]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Area]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Value]
      ,[CheckValue] as Antes

  FROM [dbo].[v_EventHistory] where type = 'OPR' 
  UNION
  SELECT distinct [EventStamp]
      ,[TagName]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Area]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Value]
      ,[CheckValue] as Antes

  FROM [dbo].[v_EventHistory] where type = 'DDE' 
)as EV order by EventStamp desc
```

With this code I miss the type , provider and operator.

I nee like this

[image]

Shared query from Hannover (Thank you)

[image]

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by that you "miss the type , provider and operator." What do you mean by "miss"? I thought you might mean that the column isn't in the result set, but it is included in the query.

Comment: Also, why `UNION` (which also forces a distinct too) when you could just have a single `SELECT` and have an `IN` in the `WHERE`.

Comment: I need to get in my result set only one record for duplicate records in the same datetime and I need my result set have the provider and operator in my query. I can´t get this. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: Clarifying question: if you have two types "OPR" and "DDE" for example for one timestamp, how would you like that displayed? It sounds like you only want one row for the timestamp. So would you have something like 
a) At least two columns (e.g., one column shows "OPR" one column on the same row shows "DDE"
b) One column [Types] that shows "OPR,DDE"
or c) something else? for example to account now you have different providers that match to each. 

You could potentially use string concatenation techniques (that may differ depending on version of SQL Server) or a PIVOT for some of the above.

Comment: @SeanBloch Yes. This is what I try to get. Only one record for the same datetime.
Like I have commnet to Hannover  If the duplicate records have diferents type, I must select the type OPR. If the duplicate records have the same type , I must select based on provider.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use IN to identify all the records with the same Event Stamp, Provider and Operator.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[v_EventHistory] 
WHERE   CAST([EventStamp] AS VARCHAR(25)) + [Provider] + [Operator] 
            IN  (   SELECT DISTINCT CAST([EventStamp] AS VARCHAR(25)) + [Provider] + [Operator] 
                    FROM [dbo].[v_EventHistory] 
                    WHERE [type] IN  ( 'OPR', 'DDE' )
                )
ORDER BY EventStamp DESC
```

Comment: Still I have duplicate records, this is what I need to avoid . I atach the result set to a better comprehension

Comment: @yaqui - there are two records due to having two different TYPE fields. Do you not want to show that field (which would make the records distinct), show only one value, or show both values in a single text field?

Comment: @Hanonver Yes, I only want to show one record for the same datetime.
If the duplicate records have diferents type, I must select the type OPR.
If the duplicate records have the same type , I must select based on provider. 
But only one records. Sorry if I don´t explain very clear.